# Class added in button with razor code I have a problem when I click the button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table in my browser with different rows I would like to enable and disable the buttons when a condition is true. I add in the button a class `.disable`. This is the code for the button:

```html
<button type="button" id="mybtn" class='btn @(value != "" ? "disabled" : "")' 
    onclick='myfunction()'>
```

I would like to show at the users that when they click on disable button they see an alert "Disabled".

This is the code of my function

```js
function myfunction() {
    if($("#mybtn").is(".disabled")) {
        alert("disabled");
    } 
    else {
        alert("enabled");
    }
}
```

When I click the disabled button the browser shows me the enabled alert.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your markup contains an error. Therefore, it should not run at all. Check you code and describe your question more precisely. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Jackdaw thank you, I edit my question goes better?

Comment: Please check your use of parentheses. They do not match here: `class='btn @((value != "" ? "disabled" : "")'` and here: `if($("#mybtn").is(".disabled")`

Comment: sorry @AstridE. I check the parentheses in my code they are correct but still not work, now I modify my question

Comment: it seems that the class it's  not added but however the button is disabled in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your approach should be a little different. If you want to make the button enabled/disabled depend on the `value` it's necessary to operate with the `disabled` attribute, not the class. Try the following:

```html
<button type="button" id="mybtn" @(value != "" ? "disabled" : "") onclick='myfunction()'>
```

Comment: Great, finally works thank you!